# Google StreetView Mountain Biking

Tags: dictionary, hardware

I'm working on a DIY google streetview for mountain biking. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I might best get decent results? I'm looking for help with everything from what kind of cameras to use to get as much imagery as possible and how I might stitch images together.

Comment: I hope your camera has some good shock absorbers for when you go riding over roots and rocks. :) Otherwise, the images will be blurry and hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting idea.

First of all, I wouldn't mount the cameras on a bike, they'd get shaken to pieces. You'll have to walk. I'm thinking of some sort of steadicam (commercial, or home-made) to keep the cameras level.

Another solution would be an aluminum pole with a bulls-eye spirit level attached to it, with the cameras mounted on top. Every few feet you'd have to put it on the ground, manually level it, and trigger the cameras. This would be slower, but also cheaper.